# Why does WWW::Mechanize GET certain pages but not others?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I'm new to Perl/HTML things. I'm trying to use `$mech->get($url)` to get something from a periodic table on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table but it kept returning error message like this:

> Error GETing
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table:
>   Forbidden at PeriodicTable.pl line 13

But `$mech->get($url)` works fine if `$url` is http://search.cpan.org/.

Any help will be much appreciated!

---

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );

$mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

my $table_url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table/";

$mech->get( $table_url );
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because Wikipedia deny access to some programs based on the User-Agent supplied on the request.

You can alias yourself to appear as a 'normal' web browser by setting the agent after instantiation and before the `get()`, for example:

```
$mech->agent( 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_4; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.1 Safari/533.17.8' );
```

That worked for me with the URL in your posting.  Shorter strings will probably work too.

(You should remove the trailing slash from the URL too I think.)

WWW::Mechanize is a subclass of [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.836/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) - see docs there for more info, including on the `agent()` method.

You should limit your use of this method of access though.  Wikipedia explicitly deny access to some spiders in their [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/robots.txt) file.  The default user agent for LWP::UserAgent (which starts with libwww) is in the list.

Comment: You should also look at the [agent_alias](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize#$mech-%243Eagent_alias%28_%24alias_%29) method, which lets you easily impersonate common browsers without having to remember that big version string.

Answer (score 1):

When you have these sorts of problems, you need to watch the HTTP transactions so you can see what the webserver is sending back to you. In this case, you'd see that Mech connects and gets  a response, but Wikipedia is declining to respond to your bot. I like [HTTP Scoop](http://www.tuffcode.com/) on the Mac.